# Upgrade svn on OS X 10.9

Tags: macos, subversion

On OS X 10.9.5, there is `/usr/bin/svn`, which is version 1.7.19 (r1643991). However, the most recent version is [1.8.13](https://subversion.apache.org/). Apperently, with version 1.7.19 I cannot access certain subversion servers.

How can I upgrade `svn`? Do I really need to download and make `svn` (or build it via homebrew)? Why is Apple keeping me out-dated with an old version?

Answer (score 1):

Easy way is installing via [Homebrew](http://brew.sh). Just need to type the following:

```
$ brew install svn
```

These are the options:

```
$ brew info svn
subversion: stable 1.8.13, devel 1.9.0-rc2
Version control system designed to be a better CVS
https://subversion.apache.org/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/blob/master/Library/Formula/subversion.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔, scons ✘
Required: sqlite ✔, openssl ✔
Optional: gpg-agent ✘
==> Options
--universal
    Build a universal binary
--with-gpg-agent
    Build with support for GPG Agent
--with-java
    Build Java bindings
--with-perl
    Build Perl bindings
--with-python
    Build with python support
--with-ruby
    Build Ruby bindings
--devel
    Install development version 1.9.0-rc2
==> Caveats
svntools have been installed to:
  /usr/local/opt/subversion/libexec
```

If you need to install homebrew, just use this sentence:

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

Comment: Is this the only way? When will Apple upgrade svn (are new macbooks set up with this old version)?

Comment: It isn't the only one but the easiest. Of course, you can download and compile yourself. About when Apple upgrade svn, I'm afraid can answer you, but I suppose that will be far enough. It's the same as git, the version on mac are outdated too.

Comment: @Walter Apple's past practice and depending on the package's version system, major and minor updates/upgrages may be applied at the next version of the operating system. Patches/revisions are only applied when a securitiy flaw has been found in a package.

Comment: So I tried to install homebrew, but got "Illegal variable name" upon entering your sentence. What's wrong? I do have macports which provides curl version 7.38 (as opposed to 7.30 in /usr/bin).

Comment: Okay, so I sorted this out and installed svn via homebrew. However, it sits in /usr/local/bin/ and is shadowed by /usr/bin/svn. Shouldn't brew make sure that the former precedes the latter in PATH? Do I have to edit my login run command or is there a more natural way?

Comment: Homebrew tells you that when you install something, but you must alter the PATH in order to `/usr/local/bin` take precedence over `/usr/bin`.